# How to parallelize the columns from a text file in SparkR

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I have a text file, which is very large file in order of few GBs and looks like this

```
23 34 45 54
43 11 49 89
09 33 76 28
44 42 24 30
```

I want to parallelize it by columns in Spark R. 1.6.0 So far I couldn't.
I used the following code to create and RDD and it parallelized by rows.

```
rdd <- SparkR:::textFile(sc, "file.txt", 4)
```

How can I parallelize it by columns?

Comment: What do you mean by how to parallelize it by column ? What do you want to parallelize ?

Comment: when rdd <- SparkR:::textFile(sc, "file.txt", 4) is executed, rows are divided across the slave nodes, but i want columns to be divided across slave nodes